# localStorage in a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon, local-storage

I am trying to access the localStorage of a page from a Firefox extension.  My understanding is that `content` gives a reference to the `window` of the current page.  When I try and access the localStorage for the page with `content.localStorage`, I think I am getting a reference to it.  However, when I try `content.localStorage.length`, I get nothing.

Attached is the code in question.

```
var myExtension = {
    init: function() {
        var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");   // browser
        if(appcontent)
            appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myExtension.onPageLoad, true);
    },

    onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
        var doc = aEvent.originalTarget;
        alert(content.localStorage) // alerts "[object XPCNativeWrapper [object Storage]]"
        alert(content.localStorage.length) // alerts nothing
    }
window.addEventListener("load", function() { myExtension.init(); }, false);
```

EDIT#1: More information.

```
try{
    alert(content.localStorage.getItem('todoData'))
    alert(content.localStorage.length)
} catch (e){
   alert(e)
}
```

The length is throwing the exception "[Exception... "Component is not available"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"

`localStorage.length` works when I have it on a standard web page in Firefox, but `content.localStorage.length` dose not work from the Firefox extension.  Now I'm confused...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a Firefox extension, you can access the localStorage object with **window.content.localStorage**, for example:

```
var ls = window.content.localStorage;
ls.setItem("myvariable", "myvalue");
var item = ls.getItem("myvariable");
```

Anything else will give you a "Component not available" error.

As an aside, globalStorage doesn't work this way. You can't use it at all with an extension because the object is only available if it's run from a server.

Comment: window.content is undefined!

Answer (score 2):

Using NsIDOMStorageManager xpcom interface you can get your local storage information.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/NsIDOMStorageManager

Answer (score 0):

use content.localStorage.wrappedJSObject.myVariable