# what's the difference between simple storage and localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, firefox-addon-sdk

In the chrome extension development,we can use `localStorage` to store something we need.Can I use `localStorage` in the firefox addon development with Addon-Builder? I have seen many  firefox addon project using `simple-storage`,what's the difference between `simple-storage` and `localStorage`?

Comment: I imagine that simple-storage was the Firefox version of localStorage before browsers settled on the localStorage spec. (Although I don't really know for sure.) Either way, you can use localStorage in both Chrome and Firefox extensions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648645/localstorage-in-a-firefox-extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main script of a Jetpack add-on doesn't have access to any DOM methods, including [`localStorage`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/local-storage/info). Consequently, [`simple-storage`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/simple-storage.html) is a natural replacement for this API. Further, `localStorage` can only save string values, whereas `simple-storage` is capable of saving booleans, numbers, arrays, `null` and plain objects.

If you want to save such non-String values in `localStorage`, you have to manually parse and serialize the object using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`. `simple-storage` provides a simple API to set and get values.

(side note: Chrome's [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) API can be used to save non-string values, but the methods are asynchronous, unlike Firefox's synchronous `simple-prefs` API.)